# Maven shade plugin picks up IDE jars?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I'm trying to use the Maven shade plugin ([according to the tutorial here](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-shade-plugin/)) to create a "fat jar" from my project.

I'm working on my project in eclipse and when I look at the (huge) resulting fat jar, I see that it contains a lot (possibly all) of classes from the Eclipse IDE code itself.

Why is it doing that and how to prevent it from doing it?

I've tried just listing a bunch of directories in the `<exclude>` `<filters>`, but the Eclipse JDT jars also have some files in jars "root" folders and its not easy to list all of these as well.

The shade `<plugin>` part of the `pom.xml` file currently looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.shade.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>vertx-unit*/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org/apache/derby/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>javax/annotation/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com/google/googlejavaformat/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org/eclipse/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>jdtCompilerAdapter.jar</exclude>
                                    <exclude>ant_tasks/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/services/org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory</exclude>
                                    <exclude>about_files/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org/osgi/**</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Starter</Main-Class>
                                    <Main-Verticle>io.thesphere.service.App</Main-Verticle>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <artifactSet />
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: maybe you could post the pom.xml ?

Comment: I don't want to post my entire `pom.xml` file, for once because its very big and also because it contains stuff I rather not publish. But I've updated my OP with the shade plugin configuration part of the `pom.xml`

Comment: Maybe you could remove full jars being listed as dependencies directly from their groupId & artifactId instead of filtering the files inside them with many filters.
Have a look at <artifactSet /> documentation: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#artifactSet